# Changing the UINavigationBar background depending on landscape/portrait?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, landscape, portrait

I want my UINavigationBar to rotate properly within my SignatureViewController. This is currently how it looks in Portrait vs Landscapemode when rotating: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2w5573a&s=5#.Uk5kgYapWrg

As you can see the UINavigationBar does not scale on the width when in landscape. My project is built as following:

**rootViewController**(*UINavgationController*) ------**Modal push**-----> **SignatureViewController**

```
(portrait only)                                    (portrait/landscape)
```

Note that I am not using a normal push to the SignatureViewController, I am using a modal one. Just in case I wanna mention this because I am not sure if it can affect the outcome in any strange way?... I have tried different approaches to change the background of the NavigationBar depending on if it is in landscape or portrait. I will post some here below:

**try nr1:** Not working

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_nav_black.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar25g.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
}
```

**try nr2:** Not working

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

 UIImage *navBarLandscape =  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar25g.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(x,x,x,x)];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_nav_black.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:navBarLandscape  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

}
```

**try nr3:** Not working

```
- (void)applicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification
{

UIView *v =  [[UIView alloc]init];

int a = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] intValue];
int w = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
int h = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
switch(a){
    case 4:
        v.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,w,h);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_nav_black.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//Have also tried with UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone...
        NSLog(@"willrotate:1");

        break;
    case 3:
        v.frame =  CGRectMake(-20,0,w-20,h+20);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar25g.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//Have also tried with UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone...
        NSLog(@"willrotate:2");
         [self.view addSubview:v];
        break;
    case 2:
        v.frame =  CGRectMake(0,-20,w,h);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_nav_black.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//Have also tried with UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone...
        NSLog(@"willrotate:3");

        break;
    case 1:
        v.frame =  CGRectMake(20,0,w-20,h+20);
        NSLog(@"willrotate:4");
        [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar25g.png"]  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//Have also tried with UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone...


}
```

Note that in **try nr3** the NSLog works but it refuses to change the background of the UINavigationBar. So, any ideas what I shall do from here ? / Regards

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to implement the `UINavigationBar` class and override one `drawRect:` method

it should work

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *navimage;
    //we will check if screen width is 320 then it will be potrait
    if(self.frame.size.width == 320) 
    {
        navimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Your Potrait nav bar image"];
    }
    else
    {
        navimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Your Landscape nav bar image"];
    }

    [navimage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Hope it helps...

and just try this for nr1 and nr2

just change the last line of code with this..if its working or not...let me know

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin; //UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
```